# Does lattice mod preserve direction?

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, st.statistics, it.information-theory

For high enough dimension $n$, the base cell of the Voronoi partition of a lattice $L_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ picked randomly from the Siegel ensemble typically has some unit-ball-like properties: it typically contains all but negligible volume of a $(1-\varepsilon)$-radius $n$-ball, and is typically nearly contained by a $(1+\varepsilon)$-radius $n$-ball.[1]

How much does the base region typically behave like a ball in other ways?

---

Round and mod operations can be defined for a lattice $L$'s Voronoi partition base cell as so: $R_L(v)=\arg\min_{\ell\in L}\|v-\ell\|$ and $\operatorname{mod}_L(v)=v-R_L(v).$

Vaguely, one can define "mod" on a ball as $\operatorname{mod}_\ast(v)=(v/\|v\|)\cdot [\|v\| - 2 \lfloor \|v\|/2 \rfloor ]$, which just reduces $v$ by lengths of 2 until it is in the unit ball at the origin.

For high enough dimension $n$ and within some radius $R>0$, then does the mod described for $L_n$ resemble $\mod_\ast$? i.e. is there some sort of typical behavior like:  $\|\operatorname{mod}_\ast(v)-\operatorname{mod}_L(v)\|<\varepsilon$ for most $v\in B(0,R)$ ?

---

[1]: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1512416

Comment: I guess no, since I suspect there are not enough Voronoi regions adjacent to the base region for a lattice-mod-reduction of a vector just slightly outside of the base region to commonly approximately correspond to that vector's length-2 reduction.

Comment: One brief comment is that as 1) approximating $\mod_L$ allows one to approximate $R_L$, and exactly (resp approximately) computing $R_L$ allows one to solve the exact (resp approximate) closest vector problem, which is thought to take exponential time, and 3) $\mod_\ast$ seems to be efficiently computable, it seems unlikely this is true (unless perhaps $\epsilon, R$ are quite large).